# Advice on different jQuery templates

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, jsrender

Im looking at different jQuery templates for a big project. The application is probably going to live for 10+ years and all plugins being brought in need to be either a part of jQuery or "well-known".
Im having some trouble of finding a suitable jQuery template. I read that the .tmpl() plugin has been cancelled and that the jsRender is not yet in beta. These can not be used because of the obvious reasons.
(source: http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2011/12/01/goodby-jquery-templates-hello-jsrender.aspx)

Do you have any other suggestions on templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout is probably the one you want, it even has two way binding so that you can do MVVM...

http://knockoutjs.com/